# $U(1)_A$ axial anomaly for $SU(N)$ gauge theory in 1+1 dimensions

Tags: symmetry, gauge-theory, symmetry-breaking, quantum-anomalies, chirality

In massless Abelian gauge theory in 1+1 dimensions, the divergence of axial current is given by
\begin{align*}
\partial_\mu j_A^\mu=\frac{e}{2\pi}\epsilon^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}=\frac{e}{\pi}F_{01}.
\end{align*}
So the axial current is not conserved due to the quantum correction (axial anomaly).
On the other hand, in massless non-Abelian $SU(N)$ gauge theory, the right hand side just changes into $\mathrm{tr}F_{01}$ and this becomes zero because the trace of generators is equal to zero $$\mathrm{tr}\ \tau^a=0.$$

So the massless non-Abelian $SU(N)$ gauge theory in 1+1 dimensions has chiral symmetry
in the quantum mechanical sense? And can we say the expectation value of chiral condensate in the vacuum is always equal to zero $$\langle \bar{\psi}\psi\rangle =0~?$$ If so, are there any other anomalies in this physics?

Comment: I know they are dual to each other and only axial currents give the anomaly but I don't know the details of non-Abelian case.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(87)91232-9